# Finding a double-spending inner conflict referencing two tips

Tags: tangle, double-spending, consensus

I think that [IOTA Transactions, Confirmation and Consensus](https://github.com/noneymous/iota-consensus-presentation) is a very good reading. It helped me a lot on understanding IOTA protocol working.

Nevertheless I have a doubt: regarding the [*Double Spend* slide](https://github.com/noneymous/iota-consensus-presentation#double-spend) how would transaction 5 see the conflict between two inner double-spending transactions referencing two tips that reference them? Checking and comparing balances of all addresses?

Answer (score 2):

[It traverses](https://github.com/iotaledger/iri/blob/dev/src/main/java/com/iota/iri/LedgerValidator.java#L52) through ancestors until it reaches a recent memory-persisted snapshot of balances, [creates a new potential state](https://github.com/iotaledger/iri/blob/dev/src/main/java/com/iota/iri/LedgerValidator.java#L291), and then [checks](https://github.com/iotaledger/iri/blob/dev/src/main/java/com/iota/iri/Snapshot.java#L151) to see whether any addresses resolve to a negative value.

Comment: Could you please update the hyperlinks since they are not there anymore? Thank you.